# Can Sphinx replace a token with a character?

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx

I am writing some documentation on card games using Sphinx and Markdown. I am generating the suit images in this way

```
<style>
red{
    color:red;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
black{
    color:black;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
</style>

Spades is <black>&#9824;</black>
Hearts is <red>&#9829;</red> 
Diamonds is <red>&#9830;</red>
Clubs is <black>&#9827;</black>
```

This is difficult to read (in the source code) and difficult to write.

It would be so much simpler if I could enter a token (say `$spades$`) and have it convert to

```
<black>&#9824;</black>
```

on output.

Does anyone know if this is possible or is there a workaround that someone can suggest?

Comment: Note that the character encoding you are using predates UTF-8 and is something web browser did before 2000. Nowadays you can simply copy paste in the related Unicode symbols and you do not need to use funny encoding.

Comment: Thanks - but the exercise was useful to me in forcing me to consider postprocessing of sphinx files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got around this by writing my own post processor

I have created my own script *makehtml* which looks for a file `postprocess.py` in the source directory and if it exists, it runs it

```
make html

FILE=source/postprocess.py
if [ -f "$FILE" ];
then
    python $FILE
fi
```

The post processor then replaces all instances of the defined tokens with the correct values in the html files created by Sphinx.

```py
"""Post processor for Sphinx make html."""
import os
TOKENS = {
    '$spades$': '<black>&#9824;</black>',
    '$hearts$': '<red>&#9829;</red>',
    '$diamonds$': '<red>&#9830;</red>',
    '$clubs$': '<black>&#9827;</black>',
}


def get_file_list(dir_name, ext=''):
    """Return the list of files in a directory."""
    file_list = os.listdir(dir_name)
    files = []
    for file_path in file_list:
        if not ext or file_path.endswith(ext):
            files.append(file_path)
    sorted_files = sorted(files)
    return sorted_files


print('postprocessing started')

build_dir = 'build/html'
files = get_file_list(build_dir, 'html')
for file in files:
    updated = False
    file_path = os.path.join(build_dir, file)
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f_html:
        text = f_html.read()
        for token, value in TOKENS.items():
            if token in text:
                text = text.replace(token, value)
                updated = True
    if updated:
        with open(file_path, 'w') as f_html:
            f_html.write(text)

print('postprocessing complete')
```

Then in `custom.css`

```css
red{
    color:red;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

black{
    color:black;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```